# Remove rows under condition in R

Tags: r

I have this dataframe

```
    time                  power hr    fr     VE     VO2   VCO2  id         
  1 1462.0104166666667    25    90    24     20     632   549   LM01-PRD-S1
  2 1462.0194444444444    25    92    23     21     679   597   LM01-PRD-S1
  3 1462.0305555555556    25    93    22     21     675   607   LM01-PRD-S1
  4 1462.0416666666667    25    93    20     19     680   577   LM01-PRD-S1
  5 1462.0520833333333    40    96    20     22     745   660   LM01-PRD-S1
  6 1462.0618055555556    40    98    21     22     764   675   LM01-PRD-S1
  7 1462.0722222222223    40    100   21     22     789   703   LM01-PRD-S1
  8 1462.0826388888888    40    100   20     23     805   734   LM01-PRD-S1
  9 1462.09375            55    105   22     26     911   843   LM01-PRD-S1
 10 1462.1041666666667    55    105   20     25     881   831   LM01-PRD-S1
 11 1462.1131944444444    55    109   19     25     895   847   LM01-PRD-S1
 12 1462.1229166666667    55    112   21     25     908   868   LM01-PRD-S1
 13 1462.1347222222223    70    120   21     28     981   947   LM01-PRD-S1
 14 1462.1451388888888    70    120   21     29     1044  1021  LM01-PRD-S1
 15 1462.1548611111111    70    122   22     27     1066  1031  LM01-PRD-S1
 16 1462.1652777777779    70    127   19     30     1136  1122  LM01-PRD-S1
 17 1462.1770833333333    85    130   20     32     1181  1218  LM01-PRD-S1
 18 1462.1868055555556    85    141   21     32     1194  1216  LM01-PRD-S1
 19 1462.1958333333334    85    139   22     34     1231  1295  LM01-PRD-S1
 20 1462.2069444444444    85    139   19     32     1193  1268  LM01-PRD-S1
 21 1462.2166666666667    100   139   21     31     1192  1274  LM01-PRD-S1
 22 1462.2291666666667    100   146   21     38     1363  1460  LM01-PRD-S1
 23 1462.2395833333333    100   150   28     50     1551  1801  LM01-PRD-S1
 24 1462.2479166666667    100   148   30     51     1499  1810  LM01-PRD-S1
 25 1462.2597222222223    115   150   30     55     1564  1883  LM01-PRD-S1
 26 1462.2708333333333    115   153   31     56     1544  1892  LM01-PRD-S1
 27 1462.2805555555556    115   157   33     59     1545  2012  LM01-PRD-S1
 28 1462.2881944444443    115   157   34     62     1647  2091  LM01-PRD-S1
 29 NA                    NA    NA    RÈcupÈ ration NA    NA    LM01-PRD-S1
 30 1462.0027777777777    65    157   39     61     1466  1940  LM01-PRD-S1
 31 1462.0131944444445    20    153   32     58     1518  1939  LM01-PRD-S1
 32 1462.0236111111112    20    148   28     50     1422  1748  LM01-PRD-S1
 33 1462.0333333333333    20    144   26     46     1222  1555  LM01-PRD-S1
 34 1462.0430555555556    20    141   22     37     963   1209  LM01-PRD-S1
 35 1462.0541666666666    20    133   22     42     1165  1464  LM01-PRD-S1
 36 1462.0645833333333    20    133   24     47     1021  1384  LM01-PRD-S1
 37 1462.0743055555556    20    130   22     40     914   1228  LM01-PRD-S1
 38 1462.0854166666666    20    130   23     38     847   1128  LM01-PRD-S1
 39 1462.0944444444444    20    120   18     32     755   998   LM01-PRD-S1
 40 1462.1069444444445    0     117   17     29     674   904   LM01-PRD-S1
 41 1462.1173611111112    0     115   20     27     587   805   LM01-PRD-S1
 42 1462.1277777777777    0     113   20     28     536   803   LM01-PRD-S1
 43 1462.1368055555556    0     112   18     26     489   744   LM01-PRD-S1
 44 1462.1479166666666    0     110   18     25     457   703   LM01-PRD-S1
 45 1462.1590277777777    0     103   19     23     419   633   LM01-PRD-S1
 46 1462.16875            0     103   17     24     479   672   LM01-PRD-S1
 47 1462.1791666666666    0     103   19     21     423   560   LM01-PRD-S1
 48 1462.1902777777777    0     100   19     22     459   609   LM01-PRD-S1
 49 1462.1993055555556    0     101   18     22     440   599   LM01-PRD-S1
 50 1462.004861111111     0     98    18     22     410   572   LM01-PRD-S1
 51 1.0416666666666666E-2 35    102   16     18     659   576   LB02-PRD-S1
 52 1.9444444444444445E-2 35    101   17     19     729   613   LB02-PRD-S1
 53 3.0555555555555555E-2 35    105   15     28     977   851   LB02-PRD-S1
 54 4.0972222222222222E-2 35    96    16     28     886   852   LB02-PRD-S1
 55 4.9999999999999996E-2 50    90    16     16     593   504   LB02-PRD-S1
 56 6.1111111111111116E-2 50    106   18     17     737   552   LB02-PRD-S1
 57 7.2222222222222229E-2 50    108   19     23     1053  775   LB02-PRD-S1
 58 8.2638888888888887E-2 50    117   17     30     1236  1008  LB02-PRD-S1
 59 9.2361111111111116E-2 65    113   18     29     1181  983   LB02-PRD-S1
 60 0.10347222222222223   65    114   15     31     1167  1016  LB02-PRD-S1
 61 0.11388888888888889   65    118   16     31     1167  1052  LB02-PRD-S1
 62 0.12430555555555556   65    114   17     28     1104  967   LB02-PRD-S1
 63 0.13402777777777777   80    120   17     35     1318  1172  LB02-PRD-S1
 64 0.1451388888888889    80    117   16     32     1236  1153  LB02-PRD-S1
 65 0.15486111111111112   80    122   17     31     1168  1094  LB02-PRD-S1
 66 0.16458333333333333   80    122   17     34     1312  1205  LB02-PRD-S1
 67 0.1763888888888889    95    126   18     37     1311  1274  LB02-PRD-S1
 68 0.18611111111111112   95    129   18     35     1248  1201  LB02-PRD-S1
 69 0.19722222222222222   95    131   15     33     1275  1196  LB02-PRD-S1
 70 0.20625000000000002   95    134   18     39     1444  1381  LB02-PRD-S1
 71 0.21736111111111112   110   134   19     43     1539  1472  LB02-PRD-S1
 72 0.22847222222222222   110   136   19     41     1417  1406  LB02-PRD-S1
 73 0.2388888888888889    110   137   20     43     1496  1437  LB02-PRD-S1
 74 0.25                  110   139   20     44     1561  1539  LB02-PRD-S1
 75 0.25972222222222224   125   142   21     46     1561  1560  LB02-PRD-S1
 76 0.26944444444444443   125   146   21     46     1535  1552  LB02-PRD-S1
 77 0.28055555555555556   125   148   23     51     1698  1703  LB02-PRD-S1
 78 0.29166666666666669   125   150   23     53     1725  1776  LB02-PRD-S1
 79 0.30069444444444443   140   151   22     52     1726  1760  LB02-PRD-S1
 80 0.31180555555555556   140   151   23     53     1713  1763  LB02-PRD-S1
 81 0.32222222222222224   140   153   25     55     1807  1836  LB02-PRD-S1
 82 0.33263888888888887   140   155   26     58     1897  1941  LB02-PRD-S1
 83 0.34375               155   153   26     59     1929  1963  LB02-PRD-S1
 84 0.35347222222222219   155   157   26     57     1843  1908  LB02-PRD-S1
 85 0.36388888888888887   155   160   28     65     1942  2065  LB02-PRD-S1
 86 0.375                 155   164   26     64     2011  2131  LB02-PRD-S1
 87 0.38472222222222219   170   166   26     65     2048  2178  LB02-PRD-S1
 88 0.39583333333333331   170   166   26     64     2069  2171  LB02-PRD-S1
 89 0.40625               170   169   25     64     2165  2269  LB02-PRD-S1
 90 0.41666666666666669   170   169   28     76     2328  2539  LB02-PRD-S1
 91 0.42638888888888887   185   169   30     76     2189  2449  LB02-PRD-S1
 92 0.4368055555555555    185   171   29     73     2225  2411  LB02-PRD-S1
 93 0.44722222222222219   185   171   29     68     2170  2292  LB02-PRD-S1
 94 0.45763888888888887   185   171   31     82     2458  2712  LB02-PRD-S1
 95 0.4680555555555555    200   171   33     89     2443  2780  LB02-PRD-S1
 96 0.47847222222222219   200   173   33     87     2465  2784  LB02-PRD-S1
 97 0.48888888888888887   200   176   32     88     2536  2853  LB02-PRD-S1
 98 0.5                   200   176   34     93     2571  2899  LB02-PRD-S1
 99 0.51041666666666663   215   176   36     98     2529  2924  LB02-PRD-S1
100 0.52083333333333337   215   179   36     105    2602  3087  LB02-PRD-S1
101 0.53125               215   179   39     111    2795  3282  LB02-PRD-S1
102 0.54097222222222219   215   181   40     118    2679  3240  LB02-PRD-S1
103 0.55208333333333337   230   179   40     113    2649  3160  LB02-PRD-S1
104 0.56180555555555556   230   179   41     111    2601  3055  LB02-PRD-S1
105 0.57291666666666663   230   176   42     116    2639  3129  LB02-PRD-S1
106 0.58263888888888882   230   181   43     126    2683  3277  LB02-PRD-S1
107 0.59375               245   181   47     123    2597  3160  LB02-PRD-S1
108 0.60416666666666663   245   181   48     128    2482  3122  LB02-PRD-S1
109 NA                    NA    NA    RÈcupÈ ration NA    NA    LB02-PRD-S1
110 9.7222222222222224E-3 20    179   42     108    2320  2830  LB02-PRD-S1
111 2.013888888888889E-2  20    173   40     106    2134  2594  LB02-PRD-S1
112 3.125E-2              20    171   37     103    1869  2531  LB02-PRD-S1
113 4.0972222222222222E-2 20    166   38     97     1438  2207  LB02-PRD-S1
114 5.1388888888888894E-2 20    164   36     88     1192  1918  LB02-PRD-S1
115 6.1805555555555558E-2 20    155   37     81     1121  1746  LB02-PRD-S1
116 7.0833333333333331E-2 20    142   32     71     1072  1585  LB02-PRD-S1
117 8.1944444444444445E-2 20    151   26     56     961   1345  LB02-PRD-S1
118 9.2361111111111116E-2 20    148   28     58     996   1367  LB02-PRD-S1
119 0.10277777777777779   20    144   24     49     858   1189  LB02-PRD-S1
120 0.11319444444444444   20    141   25     49     722   1053  LB02-PRD-S1
121 0.125                 0     136   25     42     611   895   LB02-PRD-S1
122 0.13472222222222222   0     131   26     42     642   893   LB02-PRD-S1
123 0.1451388888888889    0     129   28     44     612   874   LB02-PRD-S1
124 0.15555555555555556   0     126   24     36     544   728   LB02-PRD-S1
125 0.16527777777777777   0     127   26     40     658   840   LB02-PRD-S1
126 0.1763888888888889    0     130   23     31     511   665   LB02-PRD-S1
127 0.18611111111111112   0     126   24     39     646   815   LB02-PRD-S1
128 0.19652777777777777   0     120   25     38     527   716   LB02-PRD-S1
129 0.20694444444444446   0     120   24     36     509   684   LB02-PRD-S1
130 1462.0104166666667    25    101   20     18     712   584   GC03-PRD-S1
131 1462.0208333333333    25    99    20     17     673   551   GC03-PRD-S1
132 1462.03125            25    97    20     17     686   559   GC03-PRD-S1
133 1462.0402777777779    25    96    20     16     639   524   GC03-PRD-S1
134 1462.0506944444444    40    99    19     16     647   518   GC03-PRD-S1
135 1462.0604166666667    40    105   19     16     669   543   GC03-PRD-S1
136 1462.0729166666667    40    107   21     18     723   598   GC03-PRD-S1
137 1462.0826388888888    40    107   25     19     746   605   GC03-PRD-S1
138 1462.0916666666667    55    109   23     20     775   645   GC03-PRD-S1
139 1462.1020833333334    55    111   20     20     780   671   GC03-PRD-S1
140 1462.1118055555555    55    116   21     21     811   710   GC03-PRD-S1
141 1462.1243055555556    55    113   17     22     858   765   GC03-PRD-S1
142 1462.1340277777779    70    117   21     23     900   789   GC03-PRD-S1
143 1462.1458333333333    70    117   20     23     953   843   GC03-PRD-S1
144 1462.15625            70    120   20     25     980   882   GC03-PRD-S1
145 1462.1652777777779    70    122   22     26     1000  916   GC03-PRD-S1
146 1462.1763888888888    85    122   23     27     1049  961   GC03-PRD-S1
147 1462.1868055555556    85    126   23     28     1072  992   GC03-PRD-S1
148 1462.1965277777779    85    131   22     29     1110  1056  GC03-PRD-S1
149 1462.2076388888888    85    130   22     30     1066  1047  GC03-PRD-S1
150 1462.2173611111111    100   129   21     28     1166  1057  GC03-PRD-S1
151 1462.2284722222223    100   137   27     34     1346  1247  GC03-PRD-S1
152 1462.2395833333333    100   137   22     34     1272  1261  GC03-PRD-S1
153 1462.25               100   136   20     33     1222  1235  GC03-PRD-S1
154 1462.2590277777779    115   139   23     36     1321  1321  GC03-PRD-S1
155 1462.2701388888888    115   142   23     37     1340  1377  GC03-PRD-S1
156 1462.2798611111111    115   144   24     38     1362  1418  GC03-PRD-S1
157 1462.2909722222223    115   150   27     44     1470  1579  GC03-PRD-S1
158 1462.3013888888888    130   151   27     45     1466  1618  GC03-PRD-S1
159 1462.3125             130   153   31     54     1686  1875  GC03-PRD-S1
160 1462.3222222222223    130   155   33     59     1679  1998  GC03-PRD-S1
161 1462.3326388888888    130   157   33     59     1676  2021  GC03-PRD-S1
162 1462.3423611111111    145   157   33     61     1700  2041  GC03-PRD-S1
163 1462.3534722222223    145   160   35     64     1764  2120  GC03-PRD-S1
164 1462.3638888888888    145   160   36     67     1765  2182  GC03-PRD-S1
165 1462.3743055555556    145   162   40     71     1762  2208  GC03-PRD-S1
166 1462.0006944444444    145   162   39     69     1754  2208  GC03-PRD-S1
167 NA                    NA    NA    RÈcupÈ ration NA    NA    GC03-PRD-S1
168 1462.0097222222223    20    155   38     68     1687  2124  GC03-PRD-S1
169 1462.0194444444444    20    148   39     67     1576  1996  GC03-PRD-S1
170 1462.0298611111111    20    142   35     62     1390  1842  GC03-PRD-S1
171 1462.0409722222223    20    136   35     58     1189  1632  GC03-PRD-S1
172 1462.05               20    127   26     46     991   1337  GC03-PRD-S1
173 1462.0604166666667    20    117   21     26     776   896   GC03-PRD-S1
174 1462.0715277777779    20    115   22     31     855   1012  GC03-PRD-S1
175 1462.0819444444444    20    111   23     30     783   950   GC03-PRD-S1
176 1462.0930555555556    20    109   23     30     756   939   GC03-PRD-S1
177 1462.1020833333334    20    100   23     28     702   870   GC03-PRD-S1
178 1462.1131944444444    20    104   23     29     685   853   GC03-PRD-S1
179 1462.1236111111111    20    90    19     20     471   594   GC03-PRD-S1
180 1462.1340277777779    0     96    20     20     494   607   GC03-PRD-S1
181 1462.1444444444444    0     94    20     19     439   559   GC03-PRD-S1
182 1462.1548611111111    0     93    20     19     425   561   GC03-PRD-S1
183 1462.1638888888888    0     90    19     17     357   480   GC03-PRD-S1
184 1462.175              0     91    18     16     345   443   GC03-PRD-S1
185 1462.1854166666667    0     96    21     18     370   480   GC03-PRD-S1
186 1462.1958333333334    0     92    20     16     324   420   GC03-PRD-S1
187 1462.2076388888888    0     92    20     16     324   414   GC03-PRD-S1
188 1462.0083333333334    0     93    20     15     309   391   GC03-PRD-S1
189 1462.0104166666667    60    127   27     40     1267  1274  GT04-PRD-S1
190 1462.0201388888888    60    131   29     40     1264  1274  GT04-PRD-S1
191 1462.0305555555556    60    133   30     40     1281  1298  GT04-PRD-S1
192 1462.0402777777779    60    134   29     42     1304  1360  GT04-PRD-S1
193 1462.0513888888888    80    134   28     40     1274  1324  GT04-PRD-S1
194 1462.0625             80    137   28     40     1337  1335  GT04-PRD-S1
195 1462.0729166666667    80    144   29     45     1485  1501  GT04-PRD-S1
196 1462.0833333333333    80    144   30     50     1573  1630  GT04-PRD-S1
197 1462.0930555555556    100   148   30     47     1380  1478  GT04-PRD-S1
198 1462.1034722222223    100   150   30     49     1520  1576  GT04-PRD-S1
199 1462.1145833333333    100   153   31     50     1553  1589  GT04-PRD-S1
200 1462.1243055555556    100   151   31     55     1735  1818  GT04-PRD-S1
201 1462.1340277777779    120   153   32     65     1905  2146  GT04-PRD-S1
202 1462.1444444444444    120   151   32     62     1748  2026  GT04-PRD-S1
203 1462.1555555555556    120   160   31     61     1799  2041  GT04-PRD-S1
204 1462.1652777777779    120   160   30     64     1810  2105  GT04-PRD-S1
205 1462.1756944444444    140   164   33     73     1895  2314  GT04-PRD-S1
206 1462.1861111111111    140   162   33     72     1966  2345  GT04-PRD-S1
207 1462.1972222222223    140   166   36     79     2021  2470  GT04-PRD-S1
208 1462.2083333333333    140   166   35     76     2022  2450  GT04-PRD-S1
209 1462.2180555555556    160   164   37     78     2115  2491  GT04-PRD-S1
210 1462.2284722222223    160   169   40     82     2147  2583  GT04-PRD-S1
211 1462.2388888888888    160   169   38     83     2190  2647  GT04-PRD-S1
212 1462.2493055555556    160   173   38     85     2202  2713  GT04-PRD-S1
213 1462.2604166666667    180   171   38     88     2332  2837  GT04-PRD-S1
214 1462.2701388888888    180   171   41     95     2321  2937  GT04-PRD-S1
215 1462.28125            180   176   39     94     2358  2994  GT04-PRD-S1
216 1462.2909722222223    180   176   42     104    2339  3086  GT04-PRD-S1
217 1462.2979166666667    200   176   44     105    2444  3186  GT04-PRD-S1
218 NA                    NA    NA    RÈcupÈ ration NA    NA    GT04-PRD-S1
219 1462.0034722222222    125   179   42     97     2304  2957  GT04-PRD-S1
220 1462.0131944444445    30    171   38     92     2266  2900  GT04-PRD-S1
221 1462.0236111111112    30    166   36     93     2136  2851  GT04-PRD-S1
222 1462.0347222222222    30    166   35     91     1829  2619  GT04-PRD-S1
223 1462.0444444444445    30    162   34     83     1576  2306  GT04-PRD-S1
224 1462.0548611111112    30    160   31     65     1411  1904  GT04-PRD-S1
225 1462.0652777777777    30    155   36     78     1439  2013  GT04-PRD-S1
226 1462.0763888888889    30    153   34     69     1337  1832  GT04-PRD-S1
227 1462.0861111111112    30    153   34     66     1283  1716  GT04-PRD-S1
228 1462.0965277777777    30    144   28     49     1012  1303  GT04-PRD-S1
229 1462.1069444444445    30    134   25     41     897   1147  GT04-PRD-S1
230 1462.1180555555557    0     130   25     40     756   1051  GT04-PRD-S1
231 1462.1284722222222    0     126   20     28     500   741   GT04-PRD-S1
232 1462.1381944444445    0     123   23     27     533   712   GT04-PRD-S1
233 1462.1486111111112    0     123   23     29     548   737   GT04-PRD-S1
234 1462.1590277777777    0     117   24     24     415   560   GT04-PRD-S1
235 1462.16875            0     114   21     27     610   728   GT04-PRD-S1
236 1462.1798611111112    0     111   19     23     508   612   GT04-PRD-S1
237 1462.1902777777777    0     113   21     26     548   666   GT04-PRD-S1
238 1462.2006944444445    0     113   23     27     552   683   GT04-PRD-S1
239 1462.0020833333333    0     114   22     28     547   702   GT04-PRD-S1
```

I would like to remove all rows after words "ration" in the column VE BUT only for each id.
Meaning that I would like to remove lines 29 to 50, 109 to 129, 167 to 188, and from 218 to 239.
The word "ration" is repeated several times, and please take into account that I have several ID (I can not include it in my question because it is too long).

I tried to create at the end of each id but it did not work.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `dplyr`:

```
data %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(cumsum(VE == "ration") == 0)
```

Comment: @markhogue Can you say more about what is confusing about it? Perhaps build it up? Use `x = c('a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b')` as a test case. First look at `x == 'b'`, then look at `cumsum(x == 'b')`, then `cumsum(x == 'b') == 0`. Make sense now?

Comment: @Gregor This is a very odd use of the `cumsum` function, not at all what is explained or provided as example in the help file for the function.

Comment: It's fairly common. Using `sum` on a logical vector to count the `TRUE` values (or `mean` to find the proportion that are `TRUE`) is extremely common---and not just in R. Using `cumsum` on a logical vector to get the count to `TRUE`s "so far" is a simple extension.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming for all the `id` you'll have a row with `"ration"`, you can use `dplyr` like

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%  group_by(id) %>% slice(1:(which.max(VE == "ration") -1))
```